# Ldap filter for attribute that may not exist

Tags: attributes, filter, ldap

I have a problem with adding filter for attribute, which exist not in all members of organization unit.
I set filter like this^
    (status=Active)
But this property doesn't exist in half of members and server returns "unwilling to execute 53 error".
I wonder how should I rewrite this filter query to make it work only for objects with this attribute?
Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

- To return entries that contain a populated `status` attribute, use a `present` filter, for example, `(status=*)`.
- To return entries that do not contain a `status` attribute, negate the present filter: `(!(status=*))`.
- If the server is unwilling to execute, check that the `status` attribute is indexed for `equality` and `presence`. If do not have access to this information, check with the LDAP administrators in the appropriate organization.

#### see also

- [Microsoft: Search Filter Syntax (Active Directory)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Atlassian: How to write LDAP search filters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html)
- [IBM Domino 8.5 / 8.5.1: Using search filters with ldapsearch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_USING_SEARCH_FILTERS_WITH_LSEARCH_2023_STEPS.html)
- [Oracle: Sun Java System Directory Server Enterprise Edition 6.0 Reference - Searching the Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-0997/6n3cs0btl/index.html)
- [Red Hat: Directory Server 10 LDAP Search Filters](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/10/html/Administration_Guide/Finding_Directory_Entries-LDAP_Search_Filters.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks. In my case I think it's the third statement. But anyway marked as answer.

Comment: Dead links on this answer from 2012.